# How can I set the PHP version in PHPStorm?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

Is it possible to set the PHP version value, say 4.0+ and have PHPStorm highlight functions that wouldn't work with the oldest version? For example, for PHP4 this should highlight `static function` etc. I have a PHP installation on my PC but I don't want to install an older PHP version for every small script I have to produce.

Thanks

Comment: Why would it highlight `__construct()`? It's a perfectly valid function identifier in PHP4, it's just not being called as a constructor.

Comment: @Mchl, is static function ok?

Comment: static was avaialbe in PHP4 as well IIRC. Try `abstract` or use of visibility modifiers `public`,`protected`,`private`. Anyway, writing OO code that's supposed to work under PHP4 as well as PHP5 is a nonsensical task IMO. The object model differs too much between the two.

Comment: @Mchl `static $variable` perhaps, not `static function`

Comment: Maybe. I didn't work with PHP4 OOP

Answer (score 261, accepted):

So, you mean to highlight all pieces of code that will not work with the PHP version you are writing it in, right? That can be done here:

`Preferences` -> `Languages & Frameworks` > `PHP`

and the same on Mac:

`PhpStorm -> Preferences (⌘,)` -> `Languages & Frameworks` > `PHP`

Or with newer versions of PhpStorm in Windows:

`File` -> `Settings` -> `Languages & Frameworks` > `PHP`

[image: Sample dialogbox for mentioned prefrences]

then select your PHP version, for example, `7.0`

This is very useful when your local system runs `PHP 7.0`, for example, but production is running `PHP 5.5`.

That way PhpStorm will warn you which parts will not work in production, show proper hints during writing code according to the selected version, etc.

Comment: What version do you use? I don't have that option in mine.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that: 7.1.3

Comment: Can we do this per project or is this only "global"?

Comment: For the current version of PhpStorm: ```PhpStorm 2016.3.2```. It should be ```File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP```.

Comment: and do not forget, if you got old phpstrorm(for example 2018.x) you will not see a  7.4 in *PHP language level* !

Comment: @ryanwinchester - To do it globally, then go to "File" >> "Preferences for new projects" and set it up in there as you'd like.

Answer (score 126):

In case your field is disabled.

Probably your settings "Synchronize IDE settings with composer.json" is enabled

You may change your PHP version in `composer.json` file

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.0",
}
```

OR disable your settings in this path

```
File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Composer
```

*If you change your composer.json file - 
As [Félix Gagnon-Grenier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576767/f%C3%A9lix-gagnon-grenier*) commented,
   Keep in mind  it has effects on the way packages will be required later

Comment: This answer is not really accurate. Doing that will change the language level if (and only if) the "synchronise with composer" option is checked. Moreover, it has effects on the way packages will be required later.

Comment: It helped me understanding why the PHP language level selection was disabled.

Comment: This was Really helpful

Comment: In my case phpstorm was looking to another composer.json so I changed it and problem was solved. Thanks!

Comment: Why is PhpStorm not using `config.platform.php` for this?

Answer (score 24):

You can use [Alejandro Moreno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25762693/7311767), but sometimes you might not be able to change PHP level from closed dropdown.

You can disable "Synchronize IDE settings with composer.json" checkbox from:

<kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Setting</kbd> -> <kbd>Languages & Frameworks</kbd> -> <kbd>PHP</kbd> -> <kbd>Composer</kbd>

And after applying again open

<kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Languages & Frameworks</kbd> -> <kbd>PHP</kbd>

Here You can change PHP level from opened dropdown.

Answer (score 22):

Open the Settings dialog box by choosing **File | Settings**, then click **PHP** under **Languages & Frameworks**. The PHP page opens.

[image: Screenshot of the PHP settings]

Now you can do 2 things:

1. On the PHP page that opens you can set the "PHP Language Level".
2. You can install the PHP version that you wish locally by, for example, installing packages like wamp or xamp and then set the interpreter of your PHP on the PHP page that you opened. More info [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-local-php-interpreters.html)

Comment: Could you see that is setting 'For current project'? How can I update it for Global (all projects)?

Answer (score 5):

My composer PHP version is synchronized to the phpstorm , so to explicitly choose the php language level from the setting, **check that the option in the picture bellow is disabled.**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can set this per project, as outlined by [@Alejandro Moreno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038178/alejandro-moreno).

There is also a global setting, that allows you to set the PHP Language Level for all **NEW** projects.

<kbd>File</kbd> --> <kbd>Preferences for New Projects</kbd> --> <kbd>Languages & Frameworks</kbd> --> <kbd>PHP</kbd>

Here you can set the desired level for all future projects :-)

Answer (score 2):

in picture ..........................

IN

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On Mac, it is under PHPStorm, Preferences, Languages & Frameworks, PHP

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just like [@mohammed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59265166/2884893) my composer PHP version was synchronized to my phpstorm. so all i did was to update my composer.json php version number and it affected the whole project.

**dont forget to** `composer update` **and** `php artisan config:clear`

happy coding!